# How to identify CloudFormation template that defined IAM role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am looking at an IAM role in the console that I believe has been defined in a CloudFormation template. How do I identify the template that defined the IAM role?

Answer (score 2):

Some resources support extra tags if you use CFN to create them (S3, Security Group ...), you can see `aws:cloudformation:stack-id` in **Tags**. Currently, IAM roles and policies don't have that feature. Searching by `Physical ID` in stacks is the only way I know.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following bash script will scan all couldformation templates in your account (in all regions) and output a CSV containing a list of all IAM Roles defined.

(requires you to have the AWS CLI and be authenticated)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get a list of all AWS regions
REGIONS=$(aws ec2 describe-regions --query "Regions[*].RegionName" --output text)

# Loop through each region
for region in $REGIONS; do
    echo "Checking region: $region"

    # Get a list of all CloudFormation stacks in the region
    STACKS=$(aws cloudformation list-stacks --region "$region" --stack-status-filter CREATE_COMPLETE UPDATE_COMPLETE --query "StackSummaries[*].StackName" --output text)

    # Check if there are any stacks in this region
    if [ -n "$STACKS" ]; then
        # Loop through each stack
        for stack in $STACKS; do
            # Describe the stack resources
            RESOURCES=$(aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --region "$region" --stack-name "$stack" --query "StackResources[?ResourceType=='AWS::IAM::Role'].PhysicalResourceId" --output text)

            # Check if there are any IAM roles in this stack
            if [ -n "$RESOURCES" ]; then
                # Loop through each IAM role
                for role in $RESOURCES; do
                    echo "'$region', '$stack', '$role'"
                done
            fi
        done
    else
        echo "No stacks found in region: $region"
    fi
done
```